# How to debug C code in VSCode with lldb debugger and M1 Mac?

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm working with C for a university project. I am also using VSCode on a M1 MacBook. Unfortunately I haven't found a reasonable solution yet how to debug C code on a MacBook M1 without getting error messages that the debugger is not designed for ARM64 architectures or the debugger just runs through without paying attention to the breakpoints. I would be very grateful for any instructions or hints.

Comment: You don't use Xcode for a reason? If your project is a command line application it should work just fine in Xcode and there you can use debugger.

Comment: Thank's this was a good tip. But is there no possibility for debugging in VSCode. For small projects it is much more lightweight.